# Unable to update ionic 2 from ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I am using windows 7 32 bit OS. i already installed ionic v1.
now i try to update ionic v2 but ionic v1 also gone now.

for update process i refereed this url https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/

i used the bellow command to upgrade.

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

but in command prompt finally says log in folder please submit. i don't know where to submit and find solution.

Here i unable to submit attach files so   [view here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thirumurthy/issues/master/npm-debug.log).

The command prompt screen shot is bellow

[image: ionic 2 update failed]

please give me solution. my log details bellow.

```
133947 warn In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.0
133948 verbose If you need help, you may report this error at:
133948 verbose     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
133949 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-976d3b8c' -> 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
133949 verbose stack     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
133949 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
133949 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
133949 verbose stack
133949 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-976d3b8c' -> 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
133949 verbose stack     at Error (native)
133950 verbose cwd C:\Users\Kumar
133951 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
133952 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
133953 error node v6.9.2
133954 error npm  v3.10.9
133955 error path C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-976d3b8c
133956 error code ENOENT
133957 error errno -4058
133958 error syscall rename
133959 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-976d3b8c' -> 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
133960 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-976d3b8c' -> 'C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
133960 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
133960 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
133961 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: have you tried `npm cache clean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got this bug answer.
i fixed this issue by raising a bug report in ionic forum and got solution from speedfl

[here is the solution](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10735#issuecomment-285843195)

or direct answer here:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g cordova@6.3.1 (don't take the latest)
npm install -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

try running : 
`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

before running npm install - ionic

this command to install ionic Via NPM:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

and this one to update the ionic script

```
 ionic lib update
```

you may refer to the official docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/install.html

Comment: npm install -g ionic
is not working @devanshsadhotra

Comment: that doesnot work dude.. even i tried to run command prompt as admin then also not working. same error  @devanshsadhotra

Comment: @Kumaravel  can u tell me your npm version?

Comment: version is 3.10.9 @devanshsadhotra